# Web_Map_as_JSON from latest esri jsapi?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-flex-api, printing, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to do a print export using arcgis 10.1 and latest esri jsapi.

Is there any **out of the box way** that I can extract out `Web_Map_as_JSON` from a given webmap?

`esri.tasks.PrintTask` generates a `Web_Map_as_JSON` object on its execute method.

I can capture the request parameter while posting but I need much cleaner approach. I have to post this to another application which works as a proxy between my client and server.

Please help!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Do you want to get the raw JSON request which gets posted to the ExportWebMap geoprocessing task?

Answer (score 1):

You could try `PrintTask.prototype._getPrintDefinition(map);`
You may also want to check out this [cereal](https://github.com/odoe/cereal) library as well.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box.. I'm not sure, but you can roll out your own by following this specification:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ExportWebMap_specification/0154000004w8000000/

It's pretty daunting at first, but you do have all the data in the map and layers object. Probably the best tip I can give is for graphic layers: just call `graphics.toJson()` when you're specify its `features`.